# Sum the number of times an action happens after a phone call per each unique ID

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, sum

I am attempting to sum up what happens after a phone call while trying to collect payment.
Hung up or no answer would == 0 (non payment)
Non action would not count as anything
Call , hangup and then payment would count as a (payment)==1

```
d={'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],\
   'values':['call','hung up','no answer','non action','call','payment','call','hang up','payment',] }
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

The total here would be
2 payment
1 non payment

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  You neglected to post your coding attempt and the problem you have.  This is not a coding service or tutorial site.

Comment: If you need to translate from one notation set to another, the usual implementation is a dict.

Answer (score 1):

If you count unique "id" and "payment" frequency, does that help!

For example: count unique ID =3, Payment Frequency = 2, Now, (count unique ID - Payment Frequency) = Non-Payment.

```
Total_ID = len(df['ID'].value_counts())
Total_ID
```

This will return 3 in your case

```
Payment = df.groupby('values').count()
Payment = Payment.loc['payment']['ID']
Payment
```

This will return 2 in your case

```
Non_Payment = Total_ID - Payment
Non_Payment
```

This will return 1

Comment: Thank you, It's a much needed work-arouund

Answer (score 1):

You can use crosstab to visualize the data better:

```
d={'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],\
   'values':['call','hung up','no answer','non action','call','payment','call','hang up','payment',] }
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

df_ct = pd.crosstab(df['ID'],df['values'])
df_ct['payment'].sum() #Number of payments
df_ct['payment'].count()-df_ct['payment'].sum() #Number of non-payments
```

Output of df_ct:

```
values  call  hang up  hung up  no answer  non action  payment
ID                                                            
1          1        0        1          1           0        0
2          1        0        0          0           1        1
3          1        1        0          0           0        1

2 # Payments

1 # Non payment
```